# What is causing the outlets and ceilings fans in my home to burn out

Tags: lighting, receptacle, ceiling-fan, fire-hazard

I've got 4 ceiling fans not working, one of them crackled and flickered for a while then all of a sudden no power in back bedroom and small bathroom. No power to lights, ceiling fans and inside wall plugs next to doors but the outside wall next to window works. The lights, exhaust fan and outlets do not work in the bathroom, both rooms are next to each other.

There are 5 wall outlets that are brown and slightly melted, I noticed them when I was sitting on the floor next to the plugs but nothing was plugged into them at that time. I placed electrical tape over them to avoid using them. My dryer 240 plug stopped working and the pump to the septic tank.

We had a bad storm come through in April and light stuck our pole but lighting is constantly popping something near. I watched a tree in neighbor's yard be reduced to a splinters one morning. I'm afraid there will be a fire one day.

What can I do to see what is happening?

Comment: Yikes! You've got some serious troubles there. As a very *basic* step, can you get a multimeter and check voltage on some functioning receptacles? You should get ~ 120V. Also check the dryer - you should have ~ 240V hot-hot and ~ 120V each hot-neutral. Also upload a picture of your breaker panel, as that may provide some clues.

Comment: With the problems described after a lightning strike I would suggest having the circuits checked by an electrician because there are problems beyond most DIY folks. You may be able to find the root causes like a possible damaged splice that was causing the crackling and popping this is what electrical arcs sound like. The dryer could be a separate issue or have the same root cause but I would ask the power company to verify your feed is I damaged after the strike.  You may have multiple issues this makes troubleshooting tough. Your system may have been damaged even without a direct hit.

Comment: Yes, I suspect there is something gravely wrong with your power, and it's quite likely it's caused by a transformer poletop problem.  This could cause serious damage to your home and appliances if it continues!  For now please [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) by tying it to an email/password, or Facebook or Google, so you can log in from a cellular device to see responses and/or edit in detail. .  Then shut everything off except what you're using for testing ASAP.  If any numbers at the dryer socket are wrong,

Comment: @EdBeal Honestly I think "hire an electrician" is a **super bad** thing to say when the problem is urgent and apparently on the power company's side of things.  **The PoCo could be out in an hour and have it fixed right as rain FOR FREE**.  It could take a week to find an electrician and get them out there, even worse with the holidays and COVID.  *Hiring an electrician for the cleanup phase isn't a bad idea, since you'll want to document the damage so you can charge it to PoCo or insurance.*

Comment: What I meant to say was, do mana's test - if any numbers in the dryer socket are wrong, it's time to call the PoCo.  Correlation is not causality, but it sometimes is lol... so the lightning strikes, plus every circuit in the house being involved, really points to an outside problem.  That is in the PoCo's bailiwick.  You **report an outage** and they roll a truck and go up on the pole and fix it for free.

Comment: To followup on "the cleanup phase", once things are diagnosed and fixed (which is quite likely outside but might turn out to be in the panel in the house), you'll want to replace any device that has been damaged - any receptacles, switches, wires, appliances, etc. that show signs of arcing, burning, etc. Any device that has been weakened by these problems is likely to fail in very dramatic fashion in the future, at the worst possible moment.

Comment: The dryer plug is dead so is my dryer. I've asked my power company 3 times to come out here. They replaced something on the pole and told me to check my appliances. (That was when lighting stuck and they repaired the pole to turn our lights back on) there was one thing I forgot to add, there was a guy who installed a light in the kitchen and an outside light. He is licensed but he mayof been drunk too cause in a year's time, those 2 quit working

Comment: Does "The dryer plug is dead" mean: 1 - The dryer won't turn on or 2 - I checked with a multimeter and all readings are near 0?

Comment: What IS STILL WORKING in your house? I had something similar happen in my cabin.  The cause was a high voltage line got downed by a tree onto the lower voltage distribution lines (they were on the same power poles). It tripped most of the breakers in the panel, even though nothing was in use at the time (nobody there),  it also destroyed every  GFCI outlet in the house....had to replace them all.   You have had a major electrical incident that needs immediate attention. Hate to say it, but this is more than a DIY job.